# Problem with deriving an expression of a parametric curve using Christoffel symbol.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

Consider a particle moving in coodinate system $Z^i$. The parametric expression for the path of the particle is given by $Z^i=Z^i(t)$. The general component of the velocity vector is the time derivative of the position vector of the curve is $\frac{dR^{i}(t)}{dt}=V^i(t)=\frac{dZ^i(t)}{dt}$. Now the task is to find the derivative of $V(t)$ ie. the acceleration of the particle.

The answer to this is $A^i(t)=\frac{dV^i(t)}{dt}+\Gamma^i_{jk}V^jV^k$. Why is this? Why isn't the acceleration just $\frac{dV^i(t)}{dt}$?

The definition Christoffel symbol here is $\frac{∂Z^i}{∂Z^j}=\Gamma^k_{ij}Z_k$, where $Z_k=\frac{∂R}{∂Z^k}$

Comment: The Christoffel symbol calculates derivatives with respect to the basis. Now we are caclulating time derivatives. Why should the symbol matter in this calculation?

Comment: Because as time varies, position varies, and therefore the frame varies. Use the chain rule.

Comment: What do I have to chain rule? If I take the derivate of V I get the second time derivative of Z. Z in this problem doens't have any other definition other than $Z^i=Z^i(t)$

Comment: Back up. Write the definition of Christoffel symbols. I have no idea what your notation will be. Note that your equation $V^i = dZ/dt$ is just wrong. You need to have the frame $\partial/\partial Z^i$ in there with a summation.

Comment: The thing about the derivatives is exactly what I was thinking. But the problem is that $V^i=\frac{dZ^i}{dt}$ is not done by me it is part of the exercise.

Comment: Well, it is just wrong. Please edit to,include the definitions, as I asked.

Comment: The definitions are now there. Also fixed $V^i=\frac{dZ}{dt}$ to $V^i=\frac{dZ^i}{dt}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is so much nonsense in what you were given. So you take $R(Z)$ to be the parametrization of your manifold in terms of coordinates $Z^i$ (presumably, we're talking about a submanifold of Euclidean space, so that $R$ is a vector-valued function whose partial derivatives make sense as vectors). Then the correct equations to start with are
\begin{align*}
Z_i &= \frac{\partial R}{\partial Z^i} \quad\text{(This is the frame to which I referred.)} \\
\frac{dR}{dt} = V(t) &= \sum V^i(t) Z_i, \quad\text{where $Z_i=Z_i(R(t))$} \\
\frac{\partial Z_i}{\partial Z^j} &= \sum \Gamma^k_{ij} Z_k.
\end{align*}

Now, we differentiate the velocity to obtain the acceleration.
\begin{align*}
A(t) = \frac{dV}{dt} &= \frac d{dt}\left(\sum V^i(t)Z_i(R(t))\right) \\
&= \sum_i \frac{dV^i}{dt} Z_i + \sum_i V^i \frac d{dt}\big(Z_i(R(t))\big) \\ &=\sum_i \frac{dV^i}{dt} Z_i + \sum_{i,j} V^i\frac{\partial Z_i}{\partial Z^j}\frac{dZ^j}{dt} \\
&= \sum_i \frac{dV^i}{dt} Z_i + \sum_{i,j} V^iV^j\Big(\sum_k \Gamma^k_{ij}Z_k\Big) \\
&= \sum_i\left(\frac{dV^i}{dt} + \sum_{j,k} \Gamma^i_{kj} V^jV^k\right)Z_i.
\end{align*}
Note that in the last step, I interchanged the letters $i$ and $k$ in the final summation.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer when you are satisfied. And I would suggest you keep an eye out for sloppiness in what your instructor gives you in the future. :)

Comment: Yep I will do that. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if it will be helpful to you or not, but you might download my differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

Comment: Oh I will be sure to check that out!